# PHPhotoLibrary: error creating collection list

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, phphotolibrary

I am trying to create a collection list in Photos which will have multiple albums.

The code to create the collection list is as follows:

```
__block NSString * localId;

NSError *createFolderError;

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    // Create the folder
    PHCollectionListChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHCollectionListChangeRequest creationRequestForCollectionListWithTitle: @"My Photos"];
    localId = [[changeRequest placeholderForCreatedCollectionList] localIdentifier];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!success) {
        DebugLog(@"Creating My Photos Folder Failed... error : %@", error.description);
        return;
    }

    if(localId) {
        //Do something
    }

}];
```

But, getting error as follows:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

Earlier, it was creating folder even after getting the error, but now, I see folder not getting created under Photos application.

Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

**EDIT**

The folder is getting created in the Photos app each time, but was not reflecting. When Photos App was killed and relaunched, I can see the folder. But still, why the error is shown, remains a question.

Comment: did you fix this error ?

Comment: I tried to find it for a while, but did not find an answer. Basically, the folder was getting created for me, so I ignored it.